# difference between "I couldn't let/have him ..."

Tags: word-usage, difference, let

This is from a British TV show. Abi locks Jeff in a room so he doesn't wreck the wedding of a relative. After the wedding is over, Abi explains her action to a third person by saying:

> I couldn't have him wreck their day, could I?

Why didn't Abi use "let" and say:

> I couldn't let him wreck their day, could I?

Would there be a difference?

Answer (score 1):

Nice question.  **have** can mean "arrange/cause to occur" (I had my hair cut);  or it can mean "permit to occur" when used with negated forms of **can** or **will** (I couldn't have the puppy be chewing up our shoes, now could I?)

Comment: "Your puppy is chewing up my shoes! Do something about it! **I won't have it**!" I think that better matches the OP's context, so rather than "arrange/cause to occur", I suggest it's "**permit, tolerate, allow**" - your second possibility.

Comment: Of course. That was what I said.  **I had my hair cut** is the example of arrange/cause and the puppy is the example of **permit to occur**.  I thought the symmetry was evident.  Each example usage is enclosed in parentheses following the brief definition to which it applies.  Maybe I should put a semicolon before **or** for people who don't use symmetry but punctuation to glean meaning.

Comment: I think there has to be some explicit element expressing *volition* for the negated version to convey "refusal to permit, tolerate, allow" *(**couldn't, won't,...**)*. So, for example, *I don't have my beard trimmed by the barber* simply negates the "cause to occur" sense - it has to be *I **won't** have my beard trimmed by the barber* to negate the "permit" sense.

Comment: I agree, but have fun explaining why **don't** is not volitional.

Comment: [*I don't stand for that kind of nonsense!*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+don%27t+stand+for+that+kind+of+nonsense%22) :)